# Newtonsoft.Json dependency in a .Net Standard 2 package causes runtime error in ASP.Net Core MVC 2.0 app

Tags: asp.net-core

Sorry about the long title! I'm quite new to dotnet core so I suspect I'm running into dependency issues here, but I can't quite work out why. Here goes:

I've rebuilt a .Net 4.5.2 library as a .Net Standard 2.0 library. The library relies on Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1. I packaged the whole project up as a (local) nuget package, as that seems like the appropriate way to make it available to multiple projects. Here's the repo: https://github.com/oliver-wood/realex-hpp-dotnet-standard.

The idea is to reference this package in a dotnet core 2.0 web project. So I fired up Visual Studio and chose a vanilla ASP.Net Core MVC 2.0 app. A quick debug shows that it fires up OK. https://github.com/oliver-wood/realex-test-dotnetcore

Then I installed the nuget package, and the web project builds with no issues. BUT, as soon as I start a debug, I get a runtime error:

```
System.TypeLoadException has been thrown
"Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder' 
from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'."
```

[Picture of Runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsGsM.png)

```
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer..ctor()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider..ctor(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 options)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 configureRoutes)
at realex_test_dotnetcore.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in /Users/oliver/Dev/realex-test-dotnetcore/realex-test-dotnetcore/Startup.cs:line 41
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
at realex_test_dotnetcore.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /Users/oliver/Dev/realex-test-dotnetcore/realex-test-dotnetcore/Program.cs:line 21
at realex_test_dotnetcore.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/oliver/Dev/realex-test-dotnetcore/realex-test-dotnetcore/Program.cs:line 17
```

Looking down the stack, Json.Net is implicated, and it looks like it's being called under the hood by the Startup.cs call to `app.UseMvc()`.

It looks very much like there is a conflict between Newtonsoft.Json and the built-in dotnet core libraries, but I'm not sure how to narrow it down and rectify it. Any thoughts on how to resolve, or approach resolution, would be much appreciated!

**EDIT on 17 March after comment @will-x below**

I have rebuilt the nuget package on netstandard 1.6. This involved installing a couple more packages to fill in gaps in corefx and re-writing some of the code appropriately. Newtonsoft.Json remains the latest version, 11.0.1.

This is hardly ideal in my eyes but gets my development continuing. I'm fairly certain my customer doesn't give a monkey's but I do; I'd prefer to be using the latest versions of everything if possible, but if there are issues, I guess pragmatism wins out.

Comment: Did you manually create a nuspec in your .NET Standard project? It looks like you have the package information in your project file, but you also have this nuspec.

Comment: You're right. I did do that initially. Good spot! However, I let VS2017 create the package ultimately. I've removed that file and rebuilt everything. Happy I did that, but the problem persists :(

Comment: Did you bump the package version after doing this? Otherwise, the new package won't be pulled, and the app will keep using the old, already downloaded version.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt. Yes I made sure of increasing the version number. No dice.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem.

I am maintaining an asp.net core 2.0 project which references two nuget packages, which I also maintain.  The stable (production) build of the asp.net core project is based on dotnet sdk 2.1.4 and the two nuget packages are targeting .netstandard1.6.  Recently the asp project was upgraded to dotnet sdk 2.1.101 and the nuget packages were also upgraded to target .netstandard2.0.  The asp project compiled ok but when ran in debug I saw the exact some exception like yours.  I also thought it implicated Newtonsoft.Json so I downgraded the Newtonsoft.Json version from 11.0.1 to 10.0.3.  After that the project ran in debug, but threw an exception in the publishing process.  The exception occurred in the views precompilation step of dotnet publish process:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Internal.AssemblyMetadataGenerator.AddAssemblyMetadata(CSharpCompiler compiler, CSharpCompilation compilation, CompilationOptions compilationOptions)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Internal.PrecompileRunCommand.CompileViews(ViewCompilationInfo[] results, String assemblyname)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Internal.PrecompileRunCommand.Execute()
 at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Internal.PrecompilationApplication.Execute(String[] args)
```

I then rebuilt the nuget packages to reference .netstandard library 2.0.0 (instead of the default 2.0.1) explicitly.  With this, the asp project ran successfully in debug mode with the latest NewtonSoft.Json package.  However the views precompilation still failed.  This was when I gave up.

Currently the asp project is referencing the older versions of the  nuget packages which targeted .netstandard 1.6.  This allows the asp project upgrade to proceed.  But the shadow remains on its compatibility with .netstandard 2.0 packages.

If is urgent for you (like it is in our case due to the security vulnerability discovered for aspnetcore runtime prior to 2.0.6), perhaps you may try down-compiling your nuget packages to .netstandard 1.6.

Comment: @wil-x Thanks for the insight. You were right, and I can get past that runtime error and continue developing, which was my primary objective!

Comment: @wil-x As MickyD says, and I'm sure you agree, that this isn't "the answer", or at least we wouldn't want it to be, so I can't mark it as such. And I can't even bloody upvote it because I don't have enough reputation on here, but you win a virtual pint nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and resolved it by making sure that all my NewtonSoft.Json dependencies on my projects is version 10.0.1.

The .net core mvc middleware has the dependency on this version and I was referencing a newer version on my other projects.